# Dudas de Conceptos de R

Tags: r

Un saludo a todos, estoy iniciando en el mundo del Lenguaje R y existen ciertas instrucciones que no entiendo su propósito. Como la siguiente:

```
set.seed(12345)
data(iris)
datos<-irirs
```

Encontré que la 1era linea genera secuencias de números aleatorios pero no entiendo de que forma que afecta las siguientes lineas o con que otras instrucciones seria mas sencillo de visualizar o como pudiera emplearse en otros casos.

Al indagar encontré que la 2da linea sirve para cargar un objeto en la memoria, en este caso el objeto iris propio de R pero si intento ejecutar esta instrucción no veo el cambio significativo en ninguna pestaña de la consola o algún cambio en la secuencia del código aun si se ejecuta la 2da linea para asignar el valor de iris a un dataframe llamado datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set.seed()` es una función que sirve para establecer el estado inicial del generador de número aleatorios ([RNG](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generador_de_n%C3%BAmeros_aleatorios)), particularmente, en tu ejemplo, lo que estás haciendo es establecer la "semilla" que es cualquier número entero a partir del cual se calculan los siguientes números aleatorios (estrictamente hablando pseudo aleatorios). Hacer esto nos asegura que partiendo siempre de la misma semilla inicial, obtendremos la misma secuencia de valores aleatorios.

En R es muy importante poder compartir código reproducible, por eso, cuando se usan funciones que trabajan con el [RNG](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generador_de_n%C3%BAmeros_aleatorios), por ejemplo: `sample()`, `runif()`, `*norm()` por nombrar solo algunas, establecer una "semilla" inicial hará que los valores aleatorios sean repetibles, es decir quién reproduzca el código, obtendrá los mismos valores que originalmente el autor usó en su código.

Por ejemplo, si yo comparto este código:

```
> rnorm(10)
 [1] -0.3315776  1.1207127  0.2987237  0.7796219  1.4557851 -0.6443284 -1.5531374
 [8] -1.5977095  1.8050975 -0.4816474
```

Si intentas reproducirlo, obtendrás otra serie de números, sin embargo, al hacer esto:

```
> set.seed(12345)
> rnorm(10)
 [1]  0.5855288  0.7094660 -0.1093033 -0.4534972  0.6058875 -1.8179560  0.6300986
 [8] -0.2761841 -0.2841597 -0.9193220
```

Deberías obtener la misma serie de números.

Ahora bien, volviendo a tu pregunta, no parece que `set.seed()` tuviera algún tipo de injerencia en el código, `data(iris)` efectivamente es para cargar un `data.frame` incluído en R, en realidad tampoco es necesario hacerlo, ya que puedes acceder directamente a `iris` sin problemas y con `datos <- irirs` simplemente hacemos una copia. La generación de números aleatorios podría intervenir por ejemplo si quisieras quedarte con una muestra más chica de `iris`:

```
set.seed(12345)
datos <- iris[sample(1:nrow(iris), 5), ]
datos

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
109          6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8  virginica
131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica
113          6.8         3.0          5.5         2.1  virginica
149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3  virginica
67           5.6         3.0          4.5         1.5  versicolor
```

En este caso usamos `sample()` para generar 5 números de fila aleatorios y recortamos el `data.frame` por estos.